# Negative look-ahead in pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I know that the regex `q(?!u)` means q not followed by u.

But what if I encounter a regex `(?!u)`? Does it mean a null not followed by u or just anything but a u or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?!u)` is a *zero-width assertion* which means that it matches a *position between* characters, just like `\b` matches the position between a word character and a non-word character, or `^` matches the position at the beginning of the string.

In this case, however, it matches any position that isn't before a `u`, so when it is applied to a string like `uuuuxx` it will match after the last `u` and before the first `x`. It doesn't seem to be a very useful thing to do, but there it is.

Answer (score 2):

If used with the `/g` modifier, it will move the current search marker to just before a not u character, so further regex tests used with \G will start from there.

One potential more realistic use could be in a `split`

```
my $str = 'abcuuuuuduuuu';

my @vals = split /(?!u)/, $str;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@vals;
```

Outputs:

```
["a", "b", "cuuuuu", "duuuu"]
```